# WSO2 HTTP Response

Tags: rest, wso2, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 to send rest request, which I am able to do. But I would like to have some logic before I send the response to the client. 
The Backend Rest service returns "Successful" as a response string. I have a Java code which used to do this, and I would like to use the same logic in WSO2. The logic is simple
1. If 
   the HTTP Status is greater than eq to 200 and less than 300 and     resonseStr.equalsIgnoreCase("Successful") THEN
    return "RetCode=C;Message=Success" 
   ELSE 
   return "RetCode=F;Message=Failed because Itegration Exception";

responseStr is the response from the Backend Rest Service.
My API looks like this:

```
    <api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="TririgaApi" context="/tririga">
       <resource methods="GET" url-mapping="/employee">
          <inSequence>
             <sequence key="conf:/tririgaConf"/>
             <property name="POST_TO_URI" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
             <send>
                <endpoint>
                   <http trace="enable" method="GET" uri-template="http://{uri.var.service.host}:{uri.var.service.port}/html/en/default/rest/Integration?USERNAME={uri.var.service.user}&amp;PASSWORD={uri.var.service.pass}&amp;ioName={uri.var.wfname}"/>
                </endpoint>
             </send>
          </inSequence>
       </resource>
</api>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add an outSequence to your api and implement your mediation inside it

You can access to http status code with $axis2:HTTP_SC

You can test it's value with filter mediator

You can create a message with payloadFactory mediator

Comment: Thank you Jean, but I am quite new to WSO2, are there any examples I an use, see.

Comment: I tried add the outSequence, but I keep getting exceptions:
[2016-04-22 13:25:54,273] ERROR - RelayUtils Error while building Passthrough stream org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character
'S' (code 83) in prolog; expected '<' at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1] 
<outSequence><log><property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="Status" expression="get-property('HTTP_SC')"/>
 </log><send/></outSequence>

Comment: You get this exception when you try to add the outSequence (from WSO2 web console) or at runtime, when you receive a response from your service "Integration" ?

Comment: Hi Jean, 
Thank you for your response, I get this error after I add the outSequence. And call the service (via) browser.

Comment: use tcpmon (ESB_HOME/bin) between ESB and your endpoint and have a look at your service response : it seems that the payload and the content type are not consistent (ESB find text/xml and try to decode XML while it receive JSON)

Comment: This is what I am seeing in tcpmon:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=_wpN70xNL1vRRHW6IvRjra-KqZCsX9UH1ECJsPjOsMqbSjKF7zYp!-1207521717; path=/
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 25 Apr 2016 15:00:09 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

a
Successful
0

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://wso2.org/favicon.ico
Date: Mon, 25 Apr 2016 15:00:09 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

0

Comment: Not sure to understand : I can find HTTP 200 with content type text/html and HTTP 301 for wso2.org/favicon.ico, which is the response, why is there no payload : if the response is text/html, this is the cause for Unexpected character 'S'

Comment: An other point : you need a outSequence for the response, but also a fault sequence for the case where http status code is an error

Comment: When I run the same using SoapUI and see the Raw request/response this is what I see:
Request
GET http://fsaowlsd1:8006/html/en/default/rest/Integration?USERNAME=XXXXXX&PASSWORD=XXXXXX&ioName=triPeople%20-%20Database%20-%20Employee HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Host: fsaowlsd1:8006
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

Response

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 26 Apr 2016 13:02:48 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=7v5SqjpTHQydrYOoAX8VNyJhtDjfGfGSX2vir-iHllAvOYnAR1rU!-1207521717; path=/

Successful

Comment: So, you receive a response with content type as text/html, I think this is your problem. You can change your api to send back text/plain or change ESB config and add a messageBuilder for text/html in repository/conf/axis2.xml

Comment: Is there a sample, I tried adding the messageBuilder in the axis2.xml and it returned me some encrypted code.

Comment: This is what I see 
[2016-05-02 16:41:56,188]  INFO - TririgaApi To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:58c1a50
2-af68-412f-92be-2a8b114c7c06, Direction: response, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org
/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><ns:binary xmlns:ns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">U3VjY2Vzc2Z1bA==</ns:binary></soapenv:Body></soape
nv:Envelope>

Comment: What messageBuilder did you use ?

Comment: <outSequence> <filter source="get-property('axis2', 'HTTP_SC')" regex="^(2[0-9][0-9])$"> <then> <log level="custom"> <property name="======== SOMETHING==========" value="Inside then"/> </log> <payloadFactory media-type="text/html"> <format> RetCode=C;Message=Success </format>             <args/> </payloadFactory> <property name="messageType" value="application/html" scope="axis2"/> <send/> </then> <else> <log level="custom">         <property name="== SOMETHING===" value="Inside else"/> </log> </else> </filter> </outSequence> Error: Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException